# How to disable panel interaction?

Tags: c#, background, click, panel, interaction

I'm wondering how to **disable interacting with the panel**, so I can click on the *listbox* behind it?

I would like, when I click on the location of the *panel*, that the program does not recognize it but clicks on the *listbox* behind it.

Most users would first click a colored *panel*, rather than text from a *listbox*.
Now I have a problem because when the user clicks on the *panel*, nothing will happen.

Images:
[How does it look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DQbwt.png), [Click desination](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5qw9G.png)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I succeeded, the solution is so simple:

> `panel.Enabled = false;`